# How to search and replace a string in the lines added in the last X commits?

Tags: git, sed, replace

I made 5 commits in which I referenced some variable `FooObj`. Then I realised that `FooObj` was the wrong choice and created `BarObj`. Now I want to make a commit that replaces all instances of string `FooObj` with `BarObj` **only in the lines added** in those 5 commits.

I can't do a search & replace over the whole codebase because `FooObj` is still used correctly in many places; it must be localised to those 5 commits.

I can do this replacing manually but is there an automated way?

Answer (score 6):

You can get the list of files in the last 5 commits via `git diff --name-only HEAD~5`.  Then you can pipe that into a sed command to replace your variable name with `xargs`.

So the whole command would end up looking something this:

```
git diff --name-only HEAD~5 | xargs sed -i 's/FooObj/BarObj/g'
```

This should result in the correct files being updated for you.  Verify that the changes are correct and you can commit them as usual.

***EDIT***

Since you only want the lines changed in your commits the method won't be quite as automated but you can create a patch fix the lines and apply it which should result in the changes that you want.

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/03/git-patch-create-and-apply/

You would create a patch file and apply it via:

```
git diff HEAD~5 HEAD >> BarObjPatch.diff
//Edit the patch file to correct the changes.
//As noted in the comments, be careful as this will modify context lines
sed -i 's/FooObj/BarObj/g' BarObjPatch.diff //Can also edit file manually
git apply BarObjPatch.diff
```

This should result in the changes that you want.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer my question but I need the search & replace to be localised to the lines added in those 5 commits--not the entire files--because there are many occurences of `FooObj` in those files which have always been there (and should stay unchanged).

Comment: Sorry missed that in reading the question, updated the answer which should result in the changes that you want.

Comment: But won't that `sed` command also perform the replace on context lines and deleted lines (lines beginning with "-" in the diff)? I can make the `sed` search expression only match lines beginning with a "+", but then subsequent commits will have in the context the lines I inserted in the previous commits. I guess there isn't an automated way to do this...

Comment: Not with a single command in git, no.  But needing to make this fix really should be something that happens only occasionally.  If you are constantly needing to correct variable names, I think you need to review your workflow...

Comment: I mean not even with some commandline-fu. I can't imagine how it could be done without writing a full script.

Comment: You could get the diff patch, duplicate it and make changes to the duplicate to only search-replace "+" addition lines. Then reverse apply the original patch with `git apply --reverse patch.diff` to revert to head~5 state, then re-apply the modified dup patch :)

Answer (score 0):

This sorta thing should work (note that it will only match once per line as-is)

```
git diff HEAD~5 HEAD > original.patch
cp original.patch modified.patch
sed -i 's/^+\(.*\)FooObj/ \1BarObj/g' modified.patch
git apply --reverse original.patch
git apply modified.patch
```